# Sending mail and keeping the format of Excel sheets data

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

i am trying to create same format as in Excel sheet using html code in VBA when sending Outlook mail. help out, how to set border, color, boldiness same as in Excel sheet so that in mail it would be same view?

Here is VBA code and Excel image of what is going to be processed:

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, HtmlContent As String, i As Long, j As Long
Set rng = Range("A4:H20")
HtmlContent = "<table>"

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count + 5
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<tr>"
    For j = 3 To rng.Columns.Count + 2
        HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "<td ""col width=10%"">" & Cells(i, j).Value & "</td>"
    Next
    HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</tr>"
Next
HtmlContent = HtmlContent & "</table>"
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With xOutMail
        .To = "mail@tomail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "report"
        .HTMLBody = HtmlContent
        .Display   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Image of Excel data:

[image: processed data]

Answer (score 0):

Generally [Ron de Bruin: RangetoHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) is used.

Here are some useful variables:

```
Set MailItem = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set Inspector = MailItem.GetInspector
Set Document = Inspector.WordEditor 'Word Document
Set WordApp = Document.Application
```

If you copy the range you can use the `Document` and `WordApp` to paste it into the email.  I do this by adding keywords to the email body and pasting the copied range over the keywords.

### Building an HTML Table with CSS

This pattern can easily be expanded to add whatever CSS you want.

```
Private Type RangeCSSInfo
    BackGroundColor As String
    FontColor As String
    FontName As String
    FontSize As Double
    hasLeftBorder As Boolean
    LeftBorderWeight As Long
    LeftBorderColor As String
    hasTopBorder As Boolean
    TopBorderWeight As Long
    TopBorderColor As String
    hasRightBorder As Boolean
    RightBorderWeight As Long
    RightBorderColor As String
    hasBottomBorder As Boolean
    BottomBorderWeight As Long
    BottomBorderColor As String
End Type

Function CSSInfo(Cell As Range) As RangeCSSInfo
    Dim Info As RangeCSSInfo
    With Cell
        Info.BackGroundColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Interior.Color)
        Info.FontColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Font.Color)
        Info.FontName = .Font.Name
        Info.FontSize = .Font.Size
        
        With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            If .LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                Info.hasLeftBorder = True
                Info.LeftBorderWeight = .Weight
                Info.LeftBorderColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Color)
            End If
        End With
        
        With .Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            If .LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                Info.hasTopBorder = True
                Info.TopBorderWeight = .Weight
                Info.TopBorderColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Color)
            End If
        End With
        
        With .Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            If .LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                Info.hasRightBorder = True
                Info.RightBorderWeight = .Weight
                Info.RightBorderColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Color)
            End If
        End With
        
        With .Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            If .LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                Info.hasBottomBorder = True
                Info.BottomBorderWeight = .Weight
                Info.BottomBorderColor = ConvertLongToHex(.Color)
            End If
        End With
        
    End With
    CSSInfo = Info
End Function

Function CellToHTMLTableCell(Cell As Range, isTH As Boolean) As String
    Dim Info As RangeCSSInfo
    Info = CSSInfo(Cell)
    Dim Styles(7) As String
    
    With Info
        Styles(0) = "background-color:" & .BackGroundColor
        Styles(1) = "color:" & .BackGroundColor
        Styles(2) = "font:" & .BackGroundColor
        Styles(3) = "font-size:" & .BackGroundColor
        If .hasLeftBorder Then Styles(4) = "border-left:" & .LeftBorderWeight & "px solid " & .LeftBorderColor & ";"
        If .hasTopBorder Then Styles(5) = "border-top:" & .TopBorderWeight & "px solid " & .TopBorderColor & ";"
        If .hasRightBorder Then Styles(6) = "border-right:" & .RightBorderWeight & "px solid " & .RightBorderColor & ";"
        If .hasBottomBorder Then Styles(7) = "border-bottom:" & .BottomBorderWeight & "px solid " & .BottomBorderColor & ";"

    End With
    Dim CellType As String
    CellType = IIf(isTH, "th", "td")

    
    Dim Result(3) As String
    Result(0) = "<" & CellType & " style=" & Chr(34) & Join(Styles, "") & Chr(34)
    Result(1) = ">"
    Result(2) = Cell.Value
    Result(3) = "</" & CellType & ">"

    CellToHTMLTableCell = Join(Result, "")
End Function

Rem VBA color conversion: https://worksheetsvba.com/en/vba-color-conversion

Public Function ConvertLongToHex(lColor As Long) As String
    Dim sRed As String, sGreen As String, sBlue As String
    sRed = Right("00" & Hex(lColor Mod 256), 2)
    sGreen = Right("00" & Hex(lColor \ 2 ^ 8 Mod 256), 2)
    sBlue = Right("00" & Hex(lColor \ 2 ^ 16 Mod 256), 2)
    ConvertLongToHex = "#" & sRed & sGreen & sBlue
End Function

Function RangeToHTMLTable(Target As Range) As String
    Dim Map As New Collection
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    With Target
     
        Map.Add "<table>"
        Map.Add vbTab & "<thead>"
        Map.Add String(2, vbTab) & "<tr>"
        
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
            Map.Add String(3, vbTab) & CellToHTMLTableCell(.Cells(1, c), True)
        Next
        
        Map.Add String(2, vbTab) & "</tr>"
        Map.Add vbTab & "</thead>"
        Map.Add vbTab & "<tbody>"
    
   
        For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
            Map.Add String(2, vbTab) & "<tr>"
            
            For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                Map.Add String(3, vbTab) & CellToHTMLTableCell(.Cells(r, c), False)
            Next
            
            Map.Add String(2, vbTab) & "</tr>"
        Next
    End With
    
    Map.Add vbTab & "</tbody>"
    Map.Add "</table>"
    
    Dim Result As Variant
    ReDim Result(1 To Map.Count)
    
    For r = 1 To Map.Count
        Result(r) = Map(r)
    Next
    
    RangeToHTMLTable = Join(Result, vbNewLine)
End Function
```

### Usage

[image: Immediate Window]

### Result

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="background-color:#FFEB9Ccolor:#FFEB9Cfont:#FFEB9Cfont-size:#FFEB9Cborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">One</th>
            <th style="background-color:#FFC7CEcolor:#FFC7CEfont:#FFC7CEfont-size:#FFC7CEborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Two</th>
            <th style="background-color:#C6EFCEcolor:#C6EFCEfont:#C6EFCEfont-size:#C6EFCEborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 1</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 10</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:-4138px solid #000000;">Hello World 2</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 11</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:-4138px solid #000000;border-top:-4138px solid #000000;border-right:-4138px solid #000000;border-bottom:-4138px solid #000000;">Hello World 3</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:-4138px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 12</td>
            <td style="background-color:#FFFFFFcolor:#FFFFFFfont:#FFFFFFfont-size:#FFFFFFborder-left:2px solid #000000;border-top:2px solid #000000;border-right:2px solid #000000;border-bottom:2px solid #000000;">Hello World 12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: big thanks for answer. is there any kind of more simple and short solution?

Comment: @AlekseiKovaltsuk [Ron de Bruin: RangetoHTML](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) function is pretty simple.